# Custom UINavigationBar for MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have a `UINavigationBar` with an image for its tint to customize its appearance. However when I present the mail composer as a modal view the default `UINavigationBar` is displayed. Any suggestions how I can change that so that my custom bar is displayed?

Answer (score 2):

You can access the navigation bar directly like so:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *viewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
viewController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor]; ///< Or whatever colour you want to tint it / set the background image to, etc.
```